# Loop through object in nunjucks?

Tags: javascript, json, nunjucks

I have a file called "list.json" set up like this:

```
{
  "thing1": "Thing1",
  "thing2": "Thing2",
  "thing3": "Thing3"
}
```

How can I loop through this? I want to do something like:

```
{% for item in list%}
  <option>{{ thing }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through object properties nunjucks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20990516/loop-through-object-properties-nunjucks)

Answer (score 7):

You can try following

```
{% for key, item in list%}
  <option>{{ item }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It is not looping anything. Nothing shows up. Fails silently.

Comment: Are you able to paint `list`? I mean does it has the object or it may be possible that `list` is not set properly

Comment: How do you mean paint?

Comment: @JohnDoe - I mean show in browser i.e. what do you see when you write `{{list}}`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you imported the JSON? If not, in the render JS, add a variable:

```
list: JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('list.json'))
```

If you are using it multiple times, add a variable at the top of the file instead.

```
var LIST = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('list.json'))
```

It's also possible to use the asynchronous method, but you need some nesting:

```
fs.readFile('list.json', function(err, list) {
    env.render('template.html', {
        list: list,
        //other data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gulp, this can help you: http://www.zell-weekeat.com/nunjucks-with-gulp#Populating-HTML-with-data

Answer (score 0):

You should first create an array of objects in back end :

```
var things = [];

things.push({id : 'thing1', name : 'Thing1'});
things.push({id : 'thing2', name : 'Thing2'});
things.push({id : 'thing3', name : 'Thing3'});
```

Now on front end you would be able to loop through this array like below :

```
{% for thing in things %}
<option value="{{ thing.id }}"> {{ thing.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

I hope this will help you out.